# Specflow generates extra #End ExternalSource directives to *.feature.vb file with Scenario Outlines

Tags: vb.net, specflow

When I create a Scenario Outline in a feature file and generate the tests steps for it, Specflow automatically generate .feature.vb file where it adds some mappings for the calls to correct step definitions.

The file generation has some issues and it generates a extra `#End ExternalSource` directives to the functions. There's no starting directive. The code looks like

```
Public Overridable Sub MyScenarioOutlineName_Parameter()
    Me.MyScenarioOutlineName("Parameter", CType(Nothing,String()))
#End ExternalSource
End Sub
```

This is repeated for each of the scenario outline params. So, if I have 2 scenario outlines with 4 params each, I'll get 8 compilation problems in the file.

Manually removing the directives solves the problem, but the file is auto generated once in a while and repeating this step makes the tests unmaintainable quite quickly.

Is there some configuration or other way to get rid off this once and for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has already been [noted and addressed](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/700) by SpecFlow development team.

The fix will be part of the [upcoming 2.2.0 release](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/releases/tag/V2.2.0-preview20161020).